# how to expand html multiple select box when clicked

Tags: html

Is it possible to get a multiple select box to behave like a select box in the following way:  Only show selection box (1 row) and expand when clicked?

```
<select multiple>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

but I only want to see the empty 1 row select box until clicked and then have it expand as a dropdown with scroll bar if needed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I hope CSS is enough to solve your problem. Try something like this.

```css
select{height:20px}
select:focus{height:auto}
```

```html
    <select multiple>
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: awesome! Thank you.

Comment: This is not a good usability requirement, @DCR. After the user selects an item, e.g. item 3 Mercedes, then upon exiting the select, the user can no longer see their selection. Not good from the user's point of view.

Comment: @ManoDestra This is simplified question and simplified answer. Probably this `select` is `<select multiple ng-model="makes'>`.

Comment: Not a reflection on your answer, Alex. My comment is a reflection on the OP's requirement. It's terrible design from a usability perspective and should be avoided.

Comment: @ManoDestra, I am the only user of this particular web page and the design is really just the way I want it.  Your point in general is well taken but in this specific example the aesthetics are more pleasing to me this way!

Answer (score 0):

This accomplishes what you are looking for at a very basic level using jQuery. All options are initially hidden with CSS except the first option. Using jQuery, once the first option is clicked, then the remaining options will display.

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/byronj/fmvufoxz/4/

```
**HTML:** 

<select multiple>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

**CSS:**

select option {
   display: none;
}

select option:first-of-type, .show {
  display: block;
}


**jQuery:**

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('option').on( "click", function() {
       $('option').show();
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks but no that isnt quite what I'm looking for.  The select box needs to be just 1 row in height until clicked.  Then a dropdown with scroll bar.  The same behavior as when a select box is used without multiple

Comment: Ahh I see. I just updated the fiddle link with a couple of CSS and jQuery rules to accomplish this.

https://jsfiddle.net/byronj/fmvufoxz/14/

Answer (score -1):

I believe what you are trying to do can be accomplished by:

```html
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Try running the above snippet and see if that's what you were looking for.

Hope that helped!

Comment: thanks but no.  I'm looking for that behavior when you select multiple items in the list

Comment: You can't select multiple items using this.